# How do I read all processes in lines, not in individual words

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to read all processes from my computer in Bash and then put them in a log file. However, when I run the code below, each individual string is added to the array instead of the full line.

```
processes=($(ps -o pid,comm,%mem,%cpu))
echo ${processes[@]}
```

This is the result that I get
`PID COMM %MEM %CPU 538 /usr/sbin/distno 0.0 0.0 539 /usr/sbin/cfpref 0.1 0.0 556 /usr/libexec/Use 0.2 0.0 559 /usr/sbin/univer 0.2 0.0 560 /usr/libexec/kno 0.3 0.0 561 /System/Library/ 0.2 0.0`

How can I modify this code so that processes is an array of lines instead of strings?

PID COMM %MEM %CPU 
538 /usr/sbin/distno 0.0 0.0 
539 /usr/sbin/cfpref 0.1 0.0 
556 /usr/libexec/Use 0.2 0.0 
559 /usr/sbin/univer 0.2 0.0 
560 /usr/libexec/kno 0.3 0.0 
561 /System/Library/ 0.2 0.0

I want to read the entire process line into array instead of each string individually

Answer (score 2):

Use `readarray` (in `bash`):

```
readarray -t p < <(ps -o pid,comm,%mem,%cpu)
printf '%s\n' "${p[@]}"
```

#### edit (for bash < 4)

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a p < <(ps -o pid,comm,%mem,%cpu)
printf '%s\n' "${p[@]}"
```

Comment: This is indeed much better than my solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions! Unfortunately, I use MacOS and it does not support readarray method.

Comment: @Karl `brew install bash`

Answer (score -1):

Do as follow:

```
processes=($(ps -o pid,comm,%mem,%cpu))
echo ${processes[@]} | awk '{ for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if(i%4==0){$i=$i"\n"} }1'
```